# Element added via jquery append does not persist on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make to To Do List App. I append list elements to my task list using the `append()` function

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <title>ToDo</title>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <h2>TO DO LIST</h2>
  </head>

  <form name = "taskForm">
    Task: <input type = "text" name = "task" >
          <input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "ADD">
  </form>

  <ul class = "list">
    <li class = "item"></li>
  </ul>

</html>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input#submit').click(function(){
      var newTask = $('input[name=task]').val();
      $('.list').append('<li class = "item"' + newTask + '</li>');
  });
});
```

When I click on the Submit button, I see the new item flash on screen for a second and then disappear on its own.

Why am I witnessing this behavior?

Comment: Because the page reloads when you submit a form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are submitting the form.
When a form is submitted, the page automatically begins to redirect.

To *preserve* the behavior, `return false` to prevent the form from being submitted

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input#submit').click(function(){
      var newTask = $('input[name=task]').val();
      $('.list').append('<li class = "item"' + newTask + '</li>');
      return false;
  });
});
```

Note, this is just so you can witness the change persist. However, depending on your needs, you may need to rearrange your flow if you wish to submit the form, yet keep the appended changes. This can be done with [**$.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) submitting.

Answer (score 1):

When the button submit is pressed, the page is loaded again.

change

```
<input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "ADD">
```

with

```
<input type = "button" id = "submit" value = "ADD">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a executable example, with some errors fixed in your code:

html:

```
<form name = "taskForm">
    Task: <input type = "text" name = "task" >
      <input type = "button" id = "submit" value = "ADD">
</form>

<ul class = "list">
  <li class = "item"></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input#submit').click(function(){
     var newTask = $($('input[name="task"]')[0]).val();
     console.log(newTask)
     $('.list').append('<li class = "item">' + newTask + '</li>');
  });
});
```

Comment: What advantage does `$($('input[name="task"]')[0]).val()` have over `$('input[name=task]').val()` ?

Comment: @Sinstein $('input[name="task"]') get a elements array with "task" name.